# How to deploy Yii2 project?

Tags: php, yii2, web-deployment

I want to automate deploying Yii2 project at production server. So I have few questions. Assuming that production server just created and doesn't have any file of my project.

1. Migrations. There's all clear about `yii migrate/up` command, but what if I have rbac migration, which is deploy by `./yii migrate/up --migrationPath @yii/rbac`. Could I deploy all migrations I use in one command?
2. Translations. Have I dump my translations table and deploy it just by importing SQL-dump or is there other way?

Comment: I don't think you can really execute it in just one yii command, but you could always do `yii migrate && yii migrate --migrationPath @yii/rbac`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you need to use some CI tool like GitLab or Jenkins. It will allow you to make auto deployments on each Git commit (or whatever version control you prefer to use).

Secondly, you can import an initial SQL dump in order to not execute rbac migrations on every commit.

And thirdly, about translations. The common way is to store translations in [yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-i18n-phpmessagesource.html), it's easier to maintain. But if you use [yii\i18n\DbMessageSource](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-i18n-dbmessagesource.html) you can make changes in messages and create new ones with DB migrations.

Typical steps of deployment could be:

- pull the latests version from Git/Other version control software
- execute migrations (php yii migrate/up)
- install any new libraries. In case of [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) (composer
  install)
- run unit and functional tests (phpunit)

I hope it was helpful :)

Comment: Good idea about the CI tools! :)